# PUT REST request with C#

Tags: c#, json, curl

I need to do a PUT request with header `IDENTITY_KEY`.

Specifically, I need to do the following with C#, which I have now done with `curl`:

```
curl --request PUT \
--header IDENTITY_KEY: c956c302086a042dd0426b4e62652273e05a6ce74d0b77f8b5602e0811025066 \
--header Content-type: application/json \
--data @data.txt http://192.168.1.200:8081/data/testApp_provider/RE0025
```

Where `data.txt` contains the JSON:

```
{"observations":[{
    "value":"10.1"
   },{
    "value":"11.2",
    "timestamp":"20/12/2015T12:34:45"
   },{
    "value":"12.3",
    "timestamp":"20/12/2015T10:34:45"
   }
]}
```

How can I do that?

I tried with this code but it has not worked:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.200/data/testApp_provider/RE0025");
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Headers["IDENTITY_KEY"] = "c956c302086a042dd0426b4e62652273e05a6ce74d0b77f8b5602e081102506";

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var payload = serializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    value = "97",
                    timestamp = "20 / 12 / 2015T12:34:45"

                });
                writer.Write(payload);
            }

            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what c# code have you written?

Comment: I tried with the code that I added in the question but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
request.Headers["IDENTITY_KEY"] = "c956c302086a042dd0426b4e62652273e05a6ce74d0b77f8b5602e081102506";
```

with

```
request.Headers.Add("IDENTITY_KEY", "c956c302086a042dd0426b4e62652273e05a6ce74d0b77f8b5602e081102506");
```

Comment: Thank you, 
But now, I'm getting this error: /

_The type or namespace name 'JavaScriptSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_ 

I need any other using directive?

Comment: To serialize objects into JSON I think Json.NET by Newtonsoft is the best choice. http://www.newtonsoft.com/json